# Check if date is fall between date range using sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables
1. Eligibility
2. DebitCardTransaction

I want to update Status column to 'Y' in debitcardtransaction table if service date is fall between any of BenefitEffectiveDate & GracePeriodEndDate in eligibility table else 'N'

there are two common fields between these two tables. one is SSN & second is EIN.

for example service date is 2016-03-02 in debitcardtransaction table for SSN = 139668966 and EIN = 137580

Now I need to see if this service date is fall between BenefitEffectiveDate & GracePeriodEndDate from eligibility table which has SSN = 139668966 and EIN = 137580

For this example it does not fall between any date range of BenefitEffectiveDate & GracePeriodEndDate for SSN = 139668966 and EIN = 137580

Can someone please help me how to achieve this?

Following is eligibility table structure

```
+----------------------+--------------------+-----------+--------+
| BenefitEffectiveDate | GracePeriodEndDate |    SSN    |  EIN   |
+----------------------+--------------------+-----------+--------+
| 2016-01-01           | 2016-01-31         | 139668966 | 137580 |
| 2016-03-01           | 2016-03-30         | 139668966 | 137580 |
| 2016-04-06           | 2016-05-30         | 139668966 | 137580 |
| 2016-01-01           | 2017-02-02         | 539980084 | 137580 |
| 2016-01-01           | 2016-06-01         | 570728149 | 137580 |
| 2016-08-01           | 2016-10-02         | 570728149 | 137580 |
| 2016-01-01           | 2017-02-02         | 624621535 | 137580 |
| 2016-01-01           | 2017-02-02         | 651442905 | 137580 |
| 2016-01-01           | 2017-02-02         | 651442905 | 137580 |
+----------------------+--------------------+-----------+--------+
```

Following is DebitcardTransaction table

```
+-------------+--------+-----------+--------+
| ServiceDate |  EIN   |    SSN    | Status |
+-------------+--------+-----------+--------+
| 2016-01-20  | 137580 | 139668966 |        |
| 2016-02-01  | 137580 | 139668966 |        |
| 2016-03-02  | 137580 | 139668966 |        |
| 2016-06-02  | 137580 | 139668966 |        |
| 2016-02-02  | 137580 | 539980084 |        |
| 2016-02-02  | 137580 | 570728149 |        |
| 2016-11-02  | 137580 | 570728149 |        |
| 2016-01-01  | 137580 | 624621535 |        |
| 2016-02-01  | 137580 | 651442905 |        |
+-------------+--------+-----------+--------+
```

I am looking following output

```
+-------------+--------+-----------+--------+
| ServiceDate |  EIN   |    SSN    | Status |
+-------------+--------+-----------+--------+
| 2016-01-20  | 137580 | 139668966 | Y      |
| 2016-02-01  | 137580 | 139668966 | N      |
| 2016-03-02  | 137580 | 139668966 | Y      |
| 2016-06-02  | 137580 | 139668966 | N      |
| 2016-02-02  | 137580 | 539980084 | Y      |
| 2016-02-02  | 137580 | 570728149 | Y      |
| 2016-11-02  | 137580 | 570728149 | N      |
| 2016-01-01  | 137580 | 624621535 | Y      |
| 2016-02-01  | 137580 | 651442905 | Y      |
+-------------+--------+-----------+--------+
```

Comment: That's a good question. Clear, with sample data and expected output. The only thing missing is *What have you tried so far?* But anyway: +1 from my side!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
UPDATE  DT
SET     DT.Status = (CASE WHEN EXISTS(
                            SELECT 1
                            FROM    eligibility E
                            WHERE   E.SSN = DT.SSN AND E.EIN = DT.EIN
                                AND DT.ServiceDate BETWEEN E.BenefitEffectiveDate AND GracePeriodEndDate
                            ) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END)
FROM    DebitcardTransaction DT
```

Comment: Hi Abdul, your code might flip the same row multiple times. If there are more entries to the same combination of EID and SSN there might be random results...

Comment: thanx @Shnugo, i thought combination of EID and SSN is unique, modified the script.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example with an *updateable CTE*:

```
DECLARE @tbl1 TABLE (BenefitEffectiveDate DATE,GracePeriodEndDate DATE,SSN INT,EIN INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES
 ('2016-01-01','2016-01-31',139668966,137580 )
,('2016-03-01','2016-03-30',139668966,137580 )
,('2016-04-06','2016-05-30',139668966,137580 )
,('2016-01-01','2017-02-02',539980084,137580 )
,('2016-01-01','2016-06-01',570728149,137580 )
,('2016-08-01','2016-10-02',570728149,137580 )
,('2016-01-01','2017-02-02',624621535,137580 )
,('2016-01-01','2017-02-02',651442905,137580 )
,('2016-01-01','2017-02-02',651442905,137580 );

DECLARE @tbl2 TABLE(ServiceDate DATE,EIN INT,SSN INT,Status CHAR(1));
INSERT INTO @tbl2 VALUES
 ('2016-01-20',137580,139668966,NULL)
,('2016-02-01',137580,139668966,NULL)
,('2016-03-02',137580,139668966,NULL)
,('2016-06-02',137580,139668966,NULL)
,('2016-02-02',137580,539980084,NULL)
,('2016-02-02',137580,570728149,NULL)
,('2016-11-02',137580,570728149,NULL)
,('2016-01-01',137580,624621535,NULL)
,('2016-02-01',137580,651442905,NULL);

WITH myCTE AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                            FROM @tbl1 AS t1 
                            WHERE t1.EIN=t2.EIN
                              AND t1.SSN=t2.SSN
                              AND t2.ServiceDate>=t1.BenefitEffectiveDate
                              AND t2.ServiceDate< CAST(t1.GracePeriodEndDate AS DATETIME)+1)
                THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS NewStatus
    FROM @tbl2 AS t2
)
UPDATE myCTE SET Status = NewStatus;

SELECT * FROM @tbl2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it in one select statement and included all conditions on the join.
Please check below:

```
SELECT 
     T2.ServiceDate
    ,T2.SSN
    ,T2.EIN
    ,[Status] = CASE WHEN T1.BenefitEffectiveDate IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END
FROM DebitcardTransaction  T2
LEFT JOIN Eligibility  T1
    ON T1.SSN = T2.SSN
    AND T1.EIN = T2.EIN
    AND T2.ServiceDate BETWEEN T1.BenefitEffectiveDate AND T1.GracePeriodEndDate
GROUP BY
     T2.ServiceDate
    ,T2.SSN
    ,T2.EIN
    ,T1.BenefitEffectiveDate
ORDER BY 2
```

- Group by is to single out duplicates because of left join.
- Order by is just to mimic your exact output.

If this is just a bad data then you do not need the group by:

```
| 2016-01-01           | 2017-02-02         | 651442905 | 137580 |
| 2016-01-01           | 2017-02-02         | 651442905 | 137580 |
```